# Rails Archiving A User In A New Table And Restoring Them

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am looking for some direction on how to better handle the deletion of users, and how to restore the user. Currently, the `archive!` method creates a clone of the users data in the `archived_users` table and then it nullifies the users data. This leaves the nullified user in the `Users` table without access to the app, and a copy of their record in the `archived_users` table. Is this the best way to handle the deletion, as it takes the users data in the most recent, up-to-date state before destroying them?

Moreover, what is the best way to restore the user? Ideally, you would fetch the data from `archived_users` based on `:user_id` and repopulate the same `:user_id` in the `Users` table.

In the users_controller, the destroy method is simple

```
 def destroy
    load_user
    @user.archive!
    flash[:notice] = 'User deleted'
    redirect_to action: :index
    ...
  end
```

The archive! action in the user model

```
    def archive!
    if ArchivedUser.create(
        user_id: self.id,
        company_id: self.company_id,
        email: self.email,
        first_name: self.first_name,
        last_name: self.last_name,
        encrypted_password: self.encrypted_password,
        password_salt: self.password_salt,
        session_token: self.session_token,
        perishable_token: self.perishable_token,
        verification_key: self.verification_key,
        api_key: self.api_key
      )

      self.is_archived = true

      self.email = "#{self.email}.archived#{Time.now.to_i}"
      self.encrypted_password = nil
      self.password_salt      = nil
      self.session_token      = nil
      self.perishable_token   = nil
      self.device_id          = nil
      self.verification_key   = nil
      self.save!

      self.update_column(:api_key, nil)
      UserGroup.delete_all(:user_id => self.id)
    else
      # handle the ArchivedUser not being created properly
    end
  end
```

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Or perhaps the variable `encrypted_password` is just misused.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on that @zaph, I'll be sure to look into it after I tackle this

Comment: This is pretty cool but why not just use act_as_paranoid ?  https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid